# any one knows the solution for this?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
 Private Sub Btnlog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnlog.Click
        If txtuser.Text = "Manish" And txtpw.Text = "Nair" Then
            MessageBox.Show("welcome")
        Else

            MessageBox.Show("Try again")
            count= count() + 1
            If count = 3 Then
                Me.Close()
            End If



        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't stated the issue. However, just reading your code, you're using count() which is calling the variable count as a function. Also, count is never defined. Please try:

```
     Private Sub Btnlog_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btnlog.Click
            dim count as integer = 0 ' Define count

            If txtuser.Text = "Manish" And txtpw.Text = "Nair" Then
                MessageBox.Show("welcome")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Try again")
                count = count + 1

                If count = 3 Then
                    Me.Close()
                End If
            End If
        End Sub
```